# Use 3 optarg in two functions bash script

Tags: bash

I want to make a sniffing script with optargs.

This is the script

```
#!/bin/bash

if [[ $EUID -gt 0 ]];then 
    echo "$(basename "$0") requires root privileges"
    exit 1
fi

function help(){
    echo ""
    echo "Usage: $(basename "$0") -i interface -b mac_address"
    echo ""
    echo "      -i      Wireless interface name (monitor mode)"
    echo "      -b      BBSID wireless mac"
}

function sniff(){
    airodump-ng "$1" -w PSK -c 36 --bssid "$2"
    if [ $? -gt 0 ];then
        echo "[!] Error. Check that SSID name is Radius and channel is 7"
        exit 2
    fi
}

while getopts "h:i:b:" option;do
    case "$option" in
        h)
            help
        ;;
        i)
            i=$OPTARG
        ;;
        b)
            b=$OPTARG
        ;;
    esac
done

sniff "$i" "$b"
```

I would want to make this:

For example:

`script.sh -i wlan0 -b FF:FF:FF:FF:FF:FF`

But i cant run with -h option

Answer (score 1):

You need to change two things:

1. Since the `-h` option does not take any arguments, your first argument to `getopts` should be `hi:b:` (or `b:hi:` if you want it in alphabetical order).  That is, options that take an argument should be listed with a trailing `:`, and those that don't take an argument should be listed without a trailing `:`.
2. You probably want `exit` after calling your `help` function, otherwise, the code would continue with calling `sniff` later.

I would personally also document the `-h` option.  If there was some command line parsing error, I would call your `help` function but exit with `exit 1` afterward in a `*)` catch-all case at the end of the `case ... esac` statement.

```bsh
#!/bin/sh

cmd=$(basename "$0")

if [ "$(id -u)" -ne 0 ]; then
    printf '%s requires root privileges\n' "$cmd" >&2
    exit 1
fi

help () {
    cat <<END_HELP
Usage:
        $cmd -i interface -b mac_address
        $cmd -h

        -i      Wireless interface name (monitor mode)
        -b      BBSID wireless mac

        -h      Display this help text and terminate
END_HELP
}

sniff () {
    airodump-ng "$1" -w PSK -c 36 --bssid "$2"
    err=$?
    if [ "$err" -ne 0 ]; then
        echo '[!] Error. Check that SSID name is Radius and channel is 7' >&2
    fi
    return "$err"
}

while getopts hi:b: opt; do
    case "$opt" in
        h) help; exit ;;
        i) i=$OPTARG  ;;
        b) b=$OPTARG  ;;
        *) help; exit 1 ;;
    esac
done

sniff "$i" "$b"
```

As there is nothing in the script requiring `bash`, I turned into a `/bin/sh` script.  The test of `EUID` is more safely done with `id -u` as it's easy to otherwise set `EUID=0` in the script's environment to bypass the test.

Rather than exiting in `sniff` I let it return the exit status of the `airodump-ng` utility.  The main part of the script would then exit with that as its exit status as `sniff` is the last command in the script.